# How to calculate multiple Odds Ratios using R?

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R, so I may be asking something very easy to do.

I have a datasheet in .txt format with data to calculate multiple Fisher tests. I was able to do so by importing the table to R and then used the following script:

```
apply(data,1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x,nr=2))$p.value)
```

This returned me all p.values for my comparisons.

However, I am also interested in getting the Odds Ratio. When performing a single Fisher test (for only one of my comparisons) it gives the Odds Ratio, which I already checked that are correct.

How can I apply the formula I used to obtain all p.values to obtain the Odds Ratios?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the help doc correctly the odds ratio is stored in `estimate`. Replace `p.value` for `estimate` and you should have your odds ratio.

```
apply(data,1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x,nr=2))$estimate)
```